# Buscar dados em array para calculos

Tags: php, array

Salve Galera, estou querendo buscar dados que estão em um array multidimensional e armazenar os dados em cada variável para fazer a simulação de gastos e voos.

Não consigo tirar dados do array e adicionar na variável.

```
<?php 

$ar = 'A220-100';
$distancia = 3000;
$viagens = 3;

$avioes = [
    'A220-100' => array('Aeronave'=>'A220-100', 'Fabricante'=>'Airbus', 'Ano'=> 2016, 'Assentos'=> 133, 'Carga'=> 13.3, 'Velocidade'=>850, 'Alcance'=>4075, 'Consumo'=>2.85, 'Desgaste'=>1.3, 'Preco'=>52.500000),
    '737-500'=> array('Aeronave'=>'737-500', 'Fabricante'=>'Boeing', 'Ano'=> 1990, 'Assentos'=> 132, 'Carga'=> 15.2, 'Velocidade'=>786, 'Alcance'=>4725, 'Consumo'=>3.23, 'Desgaste'=>2.3, 'Preco'=>77.500000)
];

function Calcular(){

    if(distancia > $avioes['$a']['Alcance']){
        echo "Aviao com alcance inferior ao destino. VAI CAIR ";
    } else {

    $assentos = ($avioes['$a']['Assentos'] * 2) * $viagens;

    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que percorrer esse array e ir armazenando os valores.

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach ($avioes as $codigo => $aviao) {
    // $codigo -> 'A220-100'
    // $aviao -> array('Aeronave'=>'A220-100', 'Fabricante'=>'Airbus', 'Ano'=> 2016, 'Assentos'=> 133, 'Carga'=> 13.3, 'Velocidade'=>850, 'Alcance'=>4075, 'Consumo'=>2.85, 'Desgaste'=>1.3, 'Preco'=>52.500000)
}
```

Coloquei os comentários de como você vai conseguir acessar essas informações.
Outro ponto, você consegue declarar um array usando apenas `[ ]` ao invés de `array()` conforme o exemplo abaixo, fica mais legível :)

```
$avioes = [
'A220-100' => ['Aeronave'=>'A220-100', 'Fabricante'=>'Airbus', 'Ano'=> 2016, 'Assentos'=> 133, 'Carga'=> 13.3, 'Velocidade'=>850, 'Alcance'=>4075, 'Consumo'=>2.85, 'Desgaste'=>1.3, 'Preco'=>52.500000],
'737-500' => ['Aeronave'=>'737-500', 'Fabricante'=>'Boeing', 'Ano'=> 1990, 'Assentos'=> 132, 'Carga'=> 15.2, 'Velocidade'=>786, 'Alcance'=>4725, 'Consumo'=>3.23, 'Desgaste'=>2.3, 'Preco'=>77.500000]
];
```